# what is the function of the " ; " which comes directly aftr for loop in c++?

Tags: c++

like in this code for example

```
#include<iostream.h>
        int main(){
        int x,i;
        cout<<"Enter any number : ";
        cin>>x;
        for(i=1;i*i<=x;i++);
        cout<<"The Square Root = "<<i-1;
        }
```

I found this code but I had a problem understanding the function of the semicolon !
can any one help please ?

Comment: It's an empty statement.  All of the work is done inside the parens.

Comment: ";" here is equivalent to an empty block "{}"

Answer (score 2):

It means a `for` loop with an empty body. These loops usually change some outer scope variable inside the for loop statement itself instead of the body. In this case, it's modifying `i`. The equivalent would be:

```
for(i=1;i*i<=x;i++)
{}
```